# TextBox doesn't accept dragging files from Explorer

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, .net-4.5

I have a simple `TextBox` control inside a complex `UserControl`

[image: Textbox Control]

where I'd like to drop files from Windows Explorer.
Here is the XAML code:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtMessage" 
         AcceptsReturn="True" 
         AcceptsTab="True" 
         AllowDrop="True" 
         PreviewDragOver="TxtMessage_OnDragEnter"  
         PreviewDragEnter="TxtMessage_OnDragEnter" 
         PreviewDrop="TxtMessage_OnDrop" 
         IsEnabled="{Binding IsMessageFieldEnabled}" 
         Text="{Binding Message, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         FontSize="14">
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Enter" 
                    Command="{Binding CommandSendMessage}">
        </KeyBinding>
    </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

and here is the code behind:

```
private void TxtMessage_OnDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    IDragAndDrop dd = DataContext as IDragAndDrop;
    if (dd == null)
    {
        return;
    }   

    dd.TryDrop(e.Data);
    e.Handled = true;
}

private void TxtMessage_OnDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    IDragAndDrop dd = DataContext as IDragAndDrop;
    if (dd == null)
    {
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
        return;
    }

    e.Effects = dd.CheckForAllowedDragDrop(e.Data);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

The problem is that my code behind is not called at all. Why this might happen? What would prohibit drag & drop stuff to work on a certain control?

Comment: Is it a Silverlight or WPF app?